# Движение со смещением?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void Update () {
        GameObject[] objects;
        object = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("sometag");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, objects[0].transform.position, 2f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Нужно добавить рандомное(в фиксированных пределах) смещение конечной точки по осям x,y. Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html  думаю то, что нужно для генерации случайного числа в пределах

Comment: Когда нужно смещать? В процессе движения (типа, движущийся объект пошатывается), или смещён должен быть пункт назначения (разброс при стрельбе, например)? И ради бога, переименуйте массив, хотя бы в `objects` :)

Comment: Смещён должен быть пункт назначения, т.к. скрипт будет прикреплён к нескольким объектам и будет не комильфо, если все они в конце переместятся в одну и ту же точку. Сейчас попытаюсь сделать по примеру из документации

Answer (score 1):

В итоге получилось что-то такое:

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject somegameobject;
    float offset_x, offset_y;
    void Start () {
        randomizer();
    }

    void randomizer()
    {
        offset_x = Random.Range(5f, 17f);
        offset_y = Random.Range(5f, 7f);
    }


    void Update () {
        GameObject[] gameobjects;
        gameobjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sometag");

        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(gameobjects[0].transform.position.x + offset_x, gameobjects[0].transform.position.y + offset_y);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, offset, 2.5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```